# Find in which polygon the points in a map are

Tags: r, google-maps, geocoding

I have a shapefile of city which gives me the map of it, perfectly divided by "squares". I also can transform this shapefile in a simple data.frame with the `fortify` function from the `ggplot2` package. So far, so good.

And them I have a dataset that contains 12.000 adresses, all of them from this city, with the proper latitude and longitude of each one of these adresses, and other variables, such as income/adress. But what i dont have is the information of what square each adress belongs to. When i plot a map,  one layer with the shapefile, and another with the points representing income, its very clear where are the concentrations. But i wanted the exactly information of where (in what square) is each adress falling into.

Now, i'll try to illustrate a little more with some data. Suppose we have something like:

```
lat <- 5:12
long <- c(9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 12)
square <- c("SQ1", "SQ1", "SQ2", "SQ2", "SQ2", "SQ3", "SQ3", "SQ3")
cbind(lat, long, square)
```

(very fake data)

Which results in:

```
     lat  long square
[1,] "5"  "9"  "SQ1" 
[2,] "6"  "10" "SQ1" 
[3,] "7"  "11" "SQ2" 
[4,] "8"  "11" "SQ2" 
[5,] "9"  "12" "SQ2" 
[6,] "10" "12" "SQ3" 
[7,] "11" "13" "SQ3" 
[8,] "12" "12" "SQ3"
```

If I have one observation such as `lat = 5.5` and `long = 9.5`, I know this is a point that falls into Square 1 ("SQ1"), because it is inside the interval of latitude and longitude that makes the borders of this square. Ans this is what i want to figure out in my dataset.

I have been searching for answers for some time now and i have got nowhere so far. I really believe some package must do this already, but i havent found it yet, or i must have found a similar solution and wasnt able to extend to my case. Hope i have explained it well. Anyone has suggetions?

Answer (score 2):

Good to hear you managed to convert big part of your addresses to geo coordinates. Now, given your example data

```
lat <- 5:12
long <- c(9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 12)
square <- c("SQ1", "SQ1", "SQ2", "SQ2", "SQ2", "SQ3", "SQ3", "SQ3")
df <- cbind.data.frame(long, lat, square)
```

and R's spatial data representation of it, e.g.:

```
lst <- split(df[,-3], df[,3])
polys <- lapply(seq_along(lst), function(x) Polygons(list(Polygon(lst[[x]])), names(lst)[x]))
spolys <- SpatialPolygons(polys)
spoint <- SpatialPoints(cbind(long = 11.5, lat = 8))

plot(spolys)
plot(spoint, add=T, col="red")
```

you could use `sp::over`/`%over%` to look, which points fall into which polygons. In the above example, spatial point #1 falls into spatial polygon SQ2:

```
spoint %over% spolys
# 1 
# 2
```

Or with multiple points, e.g. spatial point #1 falls into spatial polygon SQ2, and spatial point #2 falls into spatial polygon SQ3:

```
spoints <- SpatialPoints(data.frame(long = c(11.5,12.5), lat = c(8,11)))
plot(spoints, add=T, col="blue")
spoints %over% spolys
# 1 2 
# 2 3
```

Also check out the help `?sp::over` and its vignette: When the left-hand-side is of type "SpatialPoints" and the right hand side is of type "SpatialPolygons", then `over`

> returns a numeric vector of length equal to the number of points; the
>   number is the index (number) of the polygon of y in which a point
>   falls; NA denotes the point does not fall in a polygon; if a point
>   falls in multiple polygons, the last polygon is recorded.

I also recommend looking into https://gis.stackexchange.com for these type of questions.

Comment: Thank you very much, @lukeA. But you know how i can not just visualize it, but have a column that tells me in which polygon/square the adress is? I ask this because the final idea is aggregate the  income (for example) by squares.

Comment: @Brunaw The output of `spoints %over% spolys` is your column. You can assign it to your original data frame like `df <- spoints %over% spolys`, where `spoints` is the coordinates of your addresses and `spolys` is the polygons of your shape file or your custom polygons. This needs a `library(sp)` call, if it's not loaded already.

Comment: Ok, sorry! I didnt saw it. Thank you very much again.

Comment: This is actually my full dataset. What happened last time is that i was looking the data through the number of people in it, and i should be looking by number of adresses, because some people live in the same place than others. And this reduced the total of rows to 12.000.

Comment: @Brunaw You're welcome. I dunno if this is the most efficient/appropriate way of doing in, maybe also browse through [some google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+r+"sp"+"over"+"polygon").

Comment: @Brunaw Did you buy a contingent from google or did you spread multiple queries across several days to get all 12.000 data points?

Comment: Actually I just divided the work into 3 computers and them it took me only 2 days to get all the data. I had an idea to overcome this limitation of 2500 lat/log per day, using text mining, but i didn't worked it through.  But everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, just using `point.in.polygon` from `sp`.
The only trouble is that the 'polygons' in this example are given only as the corner points, and so have to be converted to coordinates for all four points (hence the `c()` of long and rev(long)).

```
df <- read.table(text="long lat square
9   5    SQ1
10   6    SQ1
11   7    SQ2
11   8    SQ2
12   9    SQ2
12  10    SQ3
13  11    SQ3
12  12    SQ3", header=TRUE)

dfsp <- split(df, df$square)
library(sp)

sapply(dfsp, function(x)point.in.polygon(9.5, 5.5, 
   c(x$long,rev(x$long)), rep(x$lat, each=2)))
```

Gives `1` for the square that the point (9.5, 5.5) falls into.